# Dependency Property not being set

Tags: wpf, vb.net, data-binding, dependency-properties

I have created a class called **Period** which gets placed inside a UserControl called **Timetable**. I have created a dependency property for **Period** called **ContainingTimetable** so that Period can access properties of its containing timetable.

Here is the dependency property:

```
Public Shared ReadOnly ContainingTimetableProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "ContainingTimetable", GetType(Timetable), GetType(Period), new PropertyMetadata(Nothing))

Public Property ContainingTimetable As Timetable
    Get
        Return DirectCast(GetValue(ContainingTimetableProperty), Timetable)
    End Get
    Set
        SetValue(ContainingTimetableProperty, Value)
        Debug.WriteLine("Timetable has been set")
    End Set
End Property
```

Here are the controls in XAML:

```
<local:Timetable Margin="50,25,21,68" UseLayoutRounding="True" PixelToMinuteRatio="2" StartTime="9:00" x:Name="Timetable1">

     <local:Period Background="#72000000" VerticalAlignment="Top" Day="Sunday" StartTime="9:00"
                      EndTime="10:20" Margin="0,0,1,0" ContainingTimetable="{Binding ElementName=Timetable1}"/>

</local:Timetable>
```

As you can see I have bound the ContainingTimetable property of the Period to **Timetable1**. However, when I run the program the ContainingTimetable property is never set on the period. I also get this error:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=Timetable1'. BindingExpression:(no path); DataItem=null; target element is 'Period' (Name=''); target property is 'ContainingTimetable' (type 'Timetable')
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: In case `Timetable` derives from FrameworkElement, you could simply use the [`Parent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.parent.aspx) property. Also the property setter and hence the `Debug.WriteLine` may never be called. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613563.aspx) for an explanation.

Comment: @Clemens Thank you for your suggestion but as Timetable is a UserControl when I get its parent it returns a Grid. I definitly know it is not being set because I get a NullReferenceException when I reference ContainingTimetable.

Comment: Sorry, I meant Period of course. Timetable would be the Parent of Period.

Comment: @Clemens That is what I thought you meant. When I get Period.Parent it returns a grid because that is the part of the user control that it is placed in.

Comment: @Clemens Thanks to your answer I figured out a workaround and am posting an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Period.Parent to get the container. However, as Timetable is a UserControl this would just return the immidete container not the instance of the UserControl. So if the UserControl Consisted of two grids one inside another Period.Parent would return a Grid not Timetable.

To get around this you can check if the parent is a timetable and if it is not go up another level and check again. Loop through until it is of the correct type.

Here is the code:

```
    Dim TimetableObject As DependencyObject
    TimetableObject = Me.Parent

    Do While (Not TimetableObject.GetType() = GetType(WPFTimetableCreator.Timetable))
        TimetableObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(TimetableObject)
    Loop
```

In my case I changed the property into a readonly and had it set internally through this method.